# Bytefield - width of a single bit

Tags: bytefield

Is there a way to control the width of a bit in pixels on a per-diagram basis ?

I have a word in a packet with a lot of fields, my text is becoming smaller and  smaller. Is there a workaround other than editing bytefield for globally larger pixel widths?

---

**Minimum working example**

[image]
The code for the posted screenshot is here:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{31,24,23,16,15,8,7,0} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{Network Header}
      \wordbox{1}{Destination} \\
      \wordbox{1}{Source} \\
      \wordbox{1}{Length} 
    \end{rightwordgroup} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{Payload}
      \wordbox[lrt]{2}{$N$ data words} \\
      \skippedwords \\
      \wordbox[lrb]{2}{}
    \end{rightwordgroup} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{Footer}
      \wordbox{1}{Checksum}
    \end{rightwordgroup}
  \end{bytefield}
  \caption{\label{fig:mwe_packet}Sample packet}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{31,24,23,16,15,8,7,0} \\
    \bitbox{1}{\tiny{M\\E\\M}} & \bitbox{3}{SEL} & \bitbox{23}{} & \bitbox{4}{Mem\\Type} & \bitbox{4}{ID} \\    
  \end{bytefield}
  \caption{\label{fig:mwe_cmd}Cmd word}
\end{figure*}
```

---

My problem is that Figure 4 text is smaller and illegible.
Figure 3 and Figure 4 have the same width. This is okay in Figure 3 where there are no minuscule writings and fonts.

What would be cool, is to have the ability to control the width of the bit on a per-figure basis. This will give better control.

Let me know if I have been successful in explaining the problem.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to create and add here a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: That worked. getting the right width will be a matter of fine tuning. Please post this as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`bytefield`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) provides a `bitwidth` key that you can set. The default is the width of `{\tiny 99i}`. You can use something like `\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{32}` and fine-tune `bitwidth` to suit your needs.